# Apache POI (excel) performans getSheet() vs createSheet()

Tags: java, excel, performance, apache-poi

The construction is really simple, I have input list of objects (lets say 100k records), and going to put this list into excel sheet. 
I noticed, if I use createSheet() it takes just seconds to populate sheet.
If I use getSheet(for example I use template for my report), and it takes several minutes to populate report. What's explanation for that?

```
public void populateSheet(List<Objects> input) {
        XSSFSheet rowsSheet = getWorkbook().createSheet("SheetName");
        int l = 1;
        for (Objects row : input) {
             .....
        }

public void populateSheet(List<Objects> input) {
        XSSFSheet rowsSheet = getWorkbook().getSheet("SheetName");
        int l = 1;
        for (Objects row : input) {
             .....
        }
```

Comment: Does your template contains lot of stuff like cell data, several sheets, formulas, and on...?

Comment: The template has two tab's. one tab has couple charts (but they not connected with multiple lines), 
second sheet has only header

Comment: Maybe loading the chart in memory causes some loss of performance. Try using a similar template but without the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, excel files may contain a lot of hidden content, even if you see nothing when opening the file.
I would simply try to recreate a new version of the sheet, and recreate the header by copy/paste. And then, test the velocity of your program.

Comment: it was exactly what I did. initial template was created from larger file...